# jQuery, adding and removing a class on click

Tags: jquery

Here's my code so far:

```
$('.faq dd').hide();
$('.faq dt').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
});
```

I would like the DT to include an "active" class whenever someone clicks on it and then an "inactive" class whenever someone clicks on it again.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With .toggleClass, you can toggle a class.
Why would you play on 2 classes ?

```
$('.faq dd').hide();
$('.faq dt').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle('normal');
});
```

Comment: Fastest gun in the west :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), first assign inactive class to dt element and give active in toggle class. It will switch between inactive active class for dt.

```
$('.faq dd').hide();
  $('.faq dt').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('active');  
     $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
});
```